# Creating lists to pass to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is a very broad question but i would like to get your take on how to go about it. Im creating a bookingsysten for an massagestudio.

There are two different kind of massages that takes diffrent amount of time.
This means that i will have to create two diffrent scheduels.

Im thinking maybe two lists:

First list: 09,10,11,12,13
Second list: 09,930,10,1030

In my view i would like the customer to decide what kind of massage he wants and then present the correct schedule...So, how do i create these two lists in a manner that lets me pass them to a view?

EDIT:
THIS IS WHAT I GOT SO FAR:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Treatments", new List<SelectListItem>
{
   new SelectListItem {Text = "FirstMassage", Value = "1"},
   new SelectListItem {Text = "SecondMassage", Value = "2"},
```

I would like to present a different schudule depending on the customers choice, I know i am asking a lot here...I guess my first question would be, how do I create the two different schedules? 
In a list like this maybe:

```
 List<int> schedule1 = new List<int> { 0900, 1000, 1100, 1200 };
        List<int> schedule2 = new List<int> { 0930, 1000, 1030, 1100 };
```

Is it possible for me to set up a post method that passes the "right" view to a partial view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this:

```
    @Html.DropDownList("Treatments", new List<SelectListItem>
    {
       new SelectListItem {Text = "FirstMassage", Value = "1"},
       new SelectListItem {Text = "SecondMassage", Value = "2"}
},
       new { @id="ddlTreatments"} )
```

write jquery event:

```
$('#ddlTreatments').change(function(){

var SelectedValue = $(this).val();

var Url = '@Url.Acction("yourAction",yourController)';

Url = Url + 'treatmentId=' + SelectedValue;

$.ajax({

            type:"GET",

            url: Url,
            success: function(result){
                $('#dllMassageScehdule').html(result);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){

            }
        });
    });


});
```

Reutrn Dropdown list from the action as partialview as place it in a container in view

Write action that take TreatmentId and return populated dropdown of schedule:

```
public ActionResult YourAction(int treatmentId)
{

List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();

list.Add(new SelectListItem {Text = "9:00", Value = "1"})

return PartialView("PartialViewDropDownSchedule",list);

}
```

your partial view like this, i am using model as `List<SelectListItem>` you have to use your model accordind to your scenario:

```
@model List<SelectListItem>

// create dropdown using model here according to your model
```

Answer (score 2):

pass something like a `Dictionary<MassageID,MassageName>` to the view.  Let the user select what they want from a dropdown list.

When they've selected an item, Ajax back to some partialview controller that loads up the massage data based on the ID the user has selected

Comment: Thank you!
That sounds reasonable to pass that to the view into a dropdown allowing the customer to choose which massage they want...Now, when they have made their choice, the proper schedule will have to show up i a div...How do I create the two different schedules?

Comment: Have the ajax form return a partialview that takes a `Schedule` model.  Based on what they choose you populate your model accordingly.  Then use the `UpdateTargetId` in the AjaxOptions to show your partial view

Comment: Thank you for answering! Im afraid your answer is over my head, is it possible for you to show an example in code?